# Route not defined

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

This is my routes:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'book/'], function ($app) {
    $app->get('/','BooksController@index'); //get all the routes    
    $app->post('/','BooksController@store'); //store single route
    $app->get('/{id}/', 'BooksController@show'); //get single route
    $app->put('/{id}/','BooksController@update'); //update single route
    $app->delete('/{id}/','BooksController@destroy'); //delete single route
});
```

When I try to generate an URL, the system return that Route [book] not defined.

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ route('book', ['id' => $book->id]) }}">
            {{ $book->name}}
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

What I miss?

Comment: I could be due to the double slash book/ + '/', thus your routes dont seem to be correct in general ill post how I would write routes give me a minute

Comment: @utdev I try to remove the second '/', but nothing happens. Waiting your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way, thus it's more readable:

```
# Book routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'books'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'BooksController@index']);
    Route::post('store', ['as' => 'store', 'uses' => 'BooksController@store']);
    Route::get('show/{id}', ['as' => 'show', 'uses' => 'BooksController@show']);
    Route::post('update/{id}', ['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'BooksController@update']);
    Route::delete('destroy/{id}', ['as' => 'destroy', 'uses' => 'BooksController@destroy']);
});
```

I also think that you do not need the `put` method, you can use `update` + `method spoofing` in your form. For more information about method spoofing have a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't name the route

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'book/'], function ($app) {

   $app->get('/{id}/', [ 
      'as' => 'book', 
      'uses' => 'BooksController@show'
   ]);

});
```

And then you can do this

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
<li>
    <a href="{{ route('book', ['id' => $book->id]) }}">
        {{ $book->name}}
    </a>
</li>
@endforeach
```